# Is it possible to make a custom user component in Visual Studio 2010 with HTML5?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2010, custom-component

I am making a project which involves creating a custom component for Visual Studio. I have made the control with Javascript, using the Kinetic library, but can't find a way to use it as a component. Any suggestions?

Right now I fear have to recreate the control using C#, but I'd rather not do this because of the amount of work already spent on the javascript control.

Thanks in advance!

-edit-

I have done some more research and asked some colleages. Apparently it would not be possible. I'll have to come up with another solution...